# Is there a way to map this based on key?

Tags: json, mule, dataweave

Is there a way to map the below JSON example based on the keys ("A", "A-BOMB" etc)? Basically i want the client to input a word they want a definition for, and i store that in a variable. So lets say the word they're looking for is stored in vars.word, is there a way to map the dataweave so that it can find it and return the anyonyms, meaning, synonyms etc?

```
{
"A": {
    "ANTONYMS": [],
    "MEANINGS": {
        "6": [
            "Noun",
            "the 1st letter of the Roman alphabet",
            [
                "Letter",
                "Letter of the alphabet",
                "Alphabetic character"
            ],
            []
        ],
        "7": [
            "Noun",
            "the blood group whose red cells carry the A antigen",
            [
                "Blood group",
                "Blood type"
            ],
            []
        ]
    },
    "SYNONYMS": [
        "Ampere",
        "Type a",
        "Antiophthalmic factor",
        "Angstrom",
        "Adenine"
    ]
},
"A-BOMB": {
    "ANTONYMS": [],
    "MEANINGS": {},
    "SYNONYMS": [
        "Atomic bomb",
        "Fission bomb",
        "Plutonium bomb",
        "Atom bomb",
        "A-bomb"
    ]
},
"A-HORIZON": {
    "ANTONYMS": [],
    "MEANINGS": {
        "1": [
            "Noun",
            "the top layer of a soil profile; usually contains humus",
            [],
            []
        ]
    },
    "SYNONYMS": [
        "A-horizon",
        "A horizon"
    ]
}
```

}

I've tried `filterObject ((value, key) -> value startsWith vars.word)`

Not sure if i should use the filter, lookup or startsWith functions. I have no idea what I'm doing. It might not even be possible. I just don't even know where to start

Comment: What's the expected output for an input example? What didn't work for your script?

Comment: If the client inputs "A-BOMB" as the word they want the definition for, i'd want a response like the following: "A-BOMB": {
    "ANTONYMS": [],
    "MEANINGS": {},
    "SYNONYMS": [
        "Atomic bomb",
        "Fission bomb",
        "Plutonium bomb",
        "Atom bomb",
        "A-bomb"
    ]
}

Answer (score 1):

**Note**-> `startsWith` or `contains` wont fit here since your Object has all the keys starting with **A** and your requirement is to match the entire word.

I think using Just Array/Object indexing would help you here

**DW**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var ip= "A-BOMB"
---
payload[ip]
```

Alternative approach using `filterObject` along with [matches](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-core-functions-matches) would give you same result

**DW**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var ip= "A-BOMB"
---
payload filterObject ((value, key) -> key matches ip)
```

**Output**

```
{
  "ANTONYMS": [
    
  ],
  "MEANINGS": {
    
  },
  "SYNONYMS": [
    "Atomic bomb",
    "Fission bomb",
    "Plutonium bomb",
    "Atom bomb",
    "A-bomb"
  ]
}
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you so much. I've been at it for 2 days. I should have probably given up sooner and moved on to other stuff, but it bothers me when i can't solve something. I'm still learning. Thank you again.